# How do i call a function outside of Field render method in React-native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, render

Hi Experts i'm a newbie in react-native, help will appreciated.

I need to call a method name openModel() which is globally declared in Component and i have a method renderInput which renders each Input passed in Field tag. When openModel() is call inside renderInput of its Inputs on Focus. Error shows _this4.openModel is not a function. Its clearly understood that this is getting incremented because of multiple time renderInput method is called.
How do i fix this ?
**Below is short code**

```
class AddPatientForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    openModel = () => {

     this.refs.bGroup.open();

    }

    renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {

        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", height: 25, paddingRight: 5, }}>
            <Input
              ref={c => { this.textInput = c }}
              returnKeyType={input.name === "Password" ? "" : "next"}
              onSubmitEditing={() => { this.textInput._root.focus(); }}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              secureTextEntry={input.name === "Password"}
              {...input}
              onFocus={() => this.openModel()}
              keyboardType={input.name === "mobile" || input.name === "age" ? "numeric" : "default"}
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />
          </View>
        );
      }

     <Field name="patientId" component={this.renderInput} type="" validate={[alphaNumeric,required]} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please remove your `openModel()` function from `constructor` it will work for you if you define your function outside of `constructor`**

```
openModel = () => {
    this.refs.modal2.open();
}
```

you can call your function and define inside of class then directly  using `this.openModel();`

if you have globally function and define outside of class then you don't need to use `this` keywords.

Comment: thanks for responding, i tried calling func openModel() as constructor outside component but the Modal module is not working. It has to call using this.refs.modal.open()

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write `OpenModel()` like this -

```
openModel() {

     this.refs.bGroup.open();

    }
```

Hope it works !